# Fastlane Setting up iOS notification extensions

Tags: ios, fastlane, ios-extensions, fastlane-match

I have created a notification extension.
My main app id is `com.company.app`
My notification extension id is `com.company.app.notificationService`

I have created a new app id on iOS dev portal with identifier `com.company.app.notificationService` and enabled Associated Domain and Push Notifications

I call the following to have match generate a new provisioning profile.
It creates a new provisioning profile with app id as the new identifier I created in the previous step

```
match(
   git_url: "https://github.com/company/certs.git",
   type: "enterprise",
   app_identifier: ["com.company.app.notificationService"],
   readonly: !is_ci
)
```

I have added logic to apply provisioning

```
// filtered to ensure we only change the provisioning profile of the extension
update_project_provisioning(
   xcodeproj: ENV["PROJECT"],
   target_filter: ENV["com.company.app.notificationService"],
   profile: ENV["sigh_com.company.app.notificationService_enterprise_profile-path"],
   build_configuration: "Debug"
)
```

Running this I get the following error. It looks like it's comparing the provisioning profile with the main app and not with the extension, although I have added my extension target as a filter

```
error: Provisioning profile "match InHouse com.company.app.notificationService" has app ID "com.company.app.notificationService", which does not match the bundle ID "com.company.app". (in target 'Main App' from project 'Project')
```